# How to handle if no rows returned in knex.js

Tags: knex.js

I used knex.js for my project. I have a question of newbie.
For sample I have this query:

```
knex(mytable)
 .select('name')
 .where('id',1)
 .then(function(rows){
  if (rows){
   blabla
  } 
 })
.catch(function(err){
  if (err) console.log(err)
})
.finally(function(){
  knex.destroy()
})
```

My question: How can I handle if no rows returned ?

Comment: Pleas do not add fluff / noise like "thanks, Mike" for next time. Please stick to the point.

Comment: And why ? Maybe you have a response to give me ?

Comment: These are some rules of SO. This makes the post a bit long, and adds unnecessary words to the question, which are not related to the question in any way. The way of saying thanks to someone on SO is mainly by accepting an answer if you are the OP, or by upvoting. You can say an informal thanks to a person in comments, if he / she has helped you in comments itself.

Comment: You already have the answer, check within the `then()` for `rows.length` using an if else.